# Unity start Audio at specific moment

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I have a little menu which comes up with the logo coming into the screen. Now I want to add a mp3/wav which gives an audio while the logo comes into the screen. The audio should stop when the logo appearance also stops.
How can I put the audio at the exact same moment when the logo (png) appears?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is have a reference to the [`AudioSource`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html) that has the audio you want to play and use the `Play` and `Stop` methods. It is also important to assure you have the field [`PlayOnAwake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-playOnAwake.html) turned off as that will play the audio the moment the scene starts.

I do not know how you are currently moving your object, so here is a very generic answer as to how you can approach this using the information I gave above.

```
[SerializeField] private AudioSource yourAudio = null;

private void IEnumerator Movement
{
    yourAudio.Start();
    
    while(movement)
    {
         // your movement code here (assure there is a yield return null)
    }
    
    yourAudio.Stop();
}
```

With some code or more detail, I can tweak the above snippet but the main idea can be applied to however you are doing your movement. If you want to stop the audio the moment the logo appears on screen, that is a different approach, so let me know if that is what you meant.

Just for completeness, if you want to just stop or start this audio whenever your logo is visible or no longer visible, here is an approach. Be warned though, this approach will be triggered by the editor camera as well, so if something unexpected happens close or toggle off your scene view.

```
public class YourLogoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource yourAudio = null;
    
    // stop audio when invisible
    void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        yourAudio.Stop();
    }

    // start audio when visible
    void OnBecameVisible()
    {
        yourAudio.Start();
    }
}
```

By using [`OnBecameInvisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.OnBecameInvisible.html) and [`OnBecameVisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.OnBecameVisible.html), whenever the `renderer` attached to your logo is seen by **any** (including scene view) camera, the `OnBecameVisible` function is called and when it is no longer seen, the `OnBecameInvisible` is called.

Comment: The `while(movement) {  }` is extremely misleading/dangerous ;) you should at least `yield return null;` inside of it .. otherwise you crash the entire Unity Editor / built application with an endless loop ;) .. it's also `yourAudio.Play();` .. not `Start()` ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
What does the IEnumerator do?

Comment: @derHugo Sorry should have put something like `//... your movement code here` in the brackets. I was unsure how OP was handling any movement so meant it to be more generic. I'll add something there.

Comment: @Achalisma An IEnumerator is a special function that splits up large processes over many frames. As you had not added code I was unsure how you were handling the movement of your logo. If you do not know what it is, then the answer there does not really apply to you so you can ignore it. The second snippet is more general which you can use regardless of how you are moving your logo.

Comment: Yeah the code is not finished but I just wanted to know how it works in the principle. I think I understood. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

It might be an overkill solution for your simple case but you could try using **Unity Timeline**

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.5/manual/index.html

You can setup all the menu animations with sounds and then play it on click.

https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/starting-timeline-through-a-c-script-2019-3#